# HealtCheckUI in .NET - issues with icons

Tags: .net, health-check

I start play with HealthCheck in .NET 8 and I added UI to my project. However I have issues with icons.
[image]

I'm not quite sure why I have got 404 for this file.
[image]

The configuration looks really simple:

```
services.AddHealthChecksUI()
        .AddInMemoryStorage();

app.MapHealthChecks("/api/health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});
app.MapHealthChecksUI(setup =>
{
    setup.ApiPath = "/api/health";
});
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

There is an open issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/2130

**Temporary solution**

You can download fonts from their repository:
https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/src/HealthChecks.UI/assets/fonts/material.woff2

Place it on the `wwwroot/ui/resources` then instead of **material.woff2** set name **1ae4e3706fe3f478fcc1.woff2**.

If you don't have already registered static files in your Startup.cs or Program.cs then use the following code:

```
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Credits go to **[dougcunha](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/2130#issuecomment-1870582445)** from the GitHub answer.

Answer (score 2):

Include the contents of https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons in your custom.css-file.

You can add your custom.css (full path) in the Program.cs like this:

```
config.MapHealthChecksUI(options => options.AddStylesheet("...customs.css"));
```

The config variable here is of type IEndpointRouteBuilder.

The current contents are:

```
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v141/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```